# order info html all data custom page or success page magento 2

Tags: magento2

I need all product information like in screen shot

[image: information like in screen shot]

Comment: you can look into customer order view page, there you will exactly what you want, you get the idea how magento is calling there

Comment: above screen shot from there

Comment: you should look at the code how magento is doing, since this is not much related to the logic there are many files which is responsible for the. if you look at those file it pretty easy.